# Create new file Drive API Python

Tags: python, api, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a new file and upload it to Google Drive with Python using Google API libraries. On the official tutorial I have only found how to upload an existing file or create a folder, but I cannot figure out how to create a completely new file with a content.

This is basically a function to create a directory

```
def CreateFolder(name,DRIVE):
    file_metadata = {
  'name' : name,
  'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    }
    file = DRIVE.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                            fields='id').execute()
    print('Folder ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
```

Is there a way to create a new file and upload it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentations - [Create Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-create) and [Uploading Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads), these documents tell detailed description of uploading and creating new files to Drive using the API.

Creating a file without content:

```
file_metadata = {
  'name' : 'Project plan',
  'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk'
}
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print 'File ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```

Creating a file with content:

```
file_metadata = { 'name' : 'photo.jpg' }
media = MediaFileUpload('files/photo.jpg',
                        mimetype='image/jpeg')
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print 'File ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```

Hope this helps.